# Failed to send batch app notifications using facebook php SDK

Tags: php, facebook, api, notifications

I'm trying to send batch notification from my app to several app users after runing the below code I get an error in the response:

```
"{"error":{"message":"(#100) Must specify a non-empty template `param","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}"`
```

Although the template param is set...

Appreciate any help on what am i doing wrong..

Here is the code I use:

```
$batched_request = array();

foreach ($users as $idx => $user) {

$request = array(
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'relative_url'  => '/' . $user['id'].'/notifications',
       'access_token' => $app_access_token,                                    
       'template' => $template,                                    
       'href' => $href        
      ); 

 $batched_request[] = json_encode($request); 

}

$params = array('batch' => '[' . implode(',',$batched_request) . ']' );
try {

    $response = $facebook->api('/','POST',$params);


} catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
         error_log($e);               
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you post via batch api, please have in mind, that you should enclose the template & href parameter as a http query string within the "body"-key.

for example:

```
$apiCalls[] = array(
  "method" => "POST",
  "relative_url" => $user['id'] . "/notifications", 
  "body" => http_build_query(array("href" => $href, "template" => $template, "ref" => "ref_key")),
  "access_token" => $app_access_token
);
```